# Failed to execute goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.5.4:wsdl2java

Tags: java, cxf

I'm trying to generate the code from WSDL file with CXF in Maven. Currently using Java 19 which I'd like to keep.

My plugin is configured with:

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated/cxf</sourceRoot>
                            <wsdlOptions>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                    <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/wsdl/sample.wsdl</wsdl>
                                </wsdlOption>
                            </wsdlOptions>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
                        <version>4.0.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
                        <version>4.0.1</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <!--dependency>
                        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
                        <version>4.0.1</version>
                    </dependency-->
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

And always get error:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.5.4:wsdl2java (default) on project customsx: Execution default of goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.5.4:wsdl2java failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.5.4:wsdl2java: **javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/HexBinaryAdapter**

I'm familiar with the bind-api removal in Java 11, and always was able to solve usual JAXB troubles using jakarta libs.
In this particular case the error seems to come from wsdl2java itself. If I do not set the jakarta dependencies the error is exclusively on javax.xml.bind.annotation as expected. If I add the dependency the error is now on HexBinaryAdapter, which I can't seem able to solve.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

You could change the approach a bit and try my example, which worked for me:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.6</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.example.project</groupId>
  <artifactId>awi</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>awi</name>
  <description>awi</description>
  <properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
      <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.client5</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpclient5</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
<!-- those dependencies down here are relevant -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.xml.ws</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.xml.ws-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>exampleName</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>xjc</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>xjc</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
            <configuration>
              <sourceType>wsdl</sourceType>
              <sources>
                <source>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl</source>
              </sources>
              <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
              <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
              <packageName>com.example.soap.objects</packageName>
              <noPackageLevelAnnotations>true</noPackageLevelAnnotations>
            </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```